# pushing array to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to search through playlists and I can do that part fine it just when I try to organize them in to a 2d array it the results are push into every playlist instead of the one it belongs to.

```
        var search_results = [];    
        var result = [];
        //loop through playlists
        $('#playlist-menu .row').each(function(){
            var playlist_name = $('.name', this).text();

            //make the playlist active
            $('#playlist-menu .row').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass("selected");

            //loop through songs in this playlist
            $("#media-panel .row").each(function(){
                 var author  = $('.author', this).text();
                 var title = $('.title', this).text();

                 if( author.toLowerCase().indexOf(commands[1]) >=0 || title.toLowerCase().indexOf(commands[1]) >= 0){
                     //found a match
                     result.push({'author':author,'title':title});
                 }
            });

            if(result.length>0){
                search_results[playlist_name] = result;
                result = [];
            }

        });
        console.log(search_results);
```

my results are much bigger than this but here is a sample of what I'm getting back

```
    [60s: Array[2], 70s: Array[2], 80's: Array[2], 90s: Array[2], Accapella: Array[2]…]
    60s: Array[2]
    0: Object
    author: "everything I can't have"
    title: "Robin Thicke [STEP UP 2]"
    __proto__: Object
    1: Object
    author: "Toxic"
    title: "16bit Dubstep Mix ( Yael Naim Vocals )"
    __proto__: Object
    length: 2
    __proto__: Array[0]
    70s: Array[2]
    0: Object
    author: "everything I can't have"
    title: "Robin Thicke [STEP UP 2]"
    __proto__: Object
    1: Object
    author: "Toxic"
    title: "16bit Dubstep Mix ( Yael Naim Vocals )"
    __proto__: Object
    length: 2
    __proto__: Array[0]
    80's: Array[2]
```

as you can see it just going into every playlist.

can anyone see what it is I'm doing wrong ?

**UPDATED AGAIN**
I am creating a bookmarklet for [plug.dj](https://plug.dj/mixxx-s-fun-house-1) the media-panel only exists once and are not within the same DOM object.  However, I've added the child selector to make sure that is not the issue. I thought by changing the class to selected would trigger the playlist to be active, making the media show in the media panel. Then I tried to break it down so that I could see it working. I added some delays to clicks, check my targets etc. I can't seem to mimic the user experience, which is what is needed to get the media panel to populate.

that said since the media panel was not changing that is why I was getting duplicate data.

So what that leaves me with is , why would a jquery click events result differ from the users click event ?

Comment: It would be much easier to find the issue if you had wrapped things in a fiddle or snippet.

Comment: Your logic seems correct.  Where are you defining commands?

Comment: `$("#media-panel .row")` This selects every item with class `row` inside of `media-panel`. It doesn't do anything specific to the playlist you're working with. I'm guessing that's your issue? Also, the last row you process will have the class `selected`, and nothing else will.

Comment: @mplungjan commands[1] is just a string

the issue is not with get results. Its with putting results into an array where i have an array of playists each with an array of songs that matched

Comment: @Ozan I'll see if I can put together a fiddle

Comment: I scribbled up a codepen... is this accurately representing the issue? http://codepen.io/bunnymatic/pen/vEeWEM  -  I think it does.  Each of the arrays in the output includes "all" matches instead of just those in the playlist.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a `scope` in the your query of the `media-panel`.  Assuming the structure of the dom is something like this

```
<div id='playlist-menu'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='name'>60's</div>
    <div id='media-panel'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='author'>60's author 1</div>
        <div class='title'>60's title 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
        ...
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='name'>70's</div>
    <div id='media-panel'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='author'>70's author 1</div>
        <div class='title'>70's title 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
         ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You need to find the `#media-panel .row` that is *inside* the currently selected playlist, so in your js, change

```
 $("#media-panel .row").each(function(){ ... })
```

to

```
$("#media-panel .row", this).each(function(){ ... })
```

or

```
$(this).find('#media-panel .row').each( ... )
```

Granted - I'm assuming the DOM structure.  If I'm off on that, please post a snippet of the actual HTML.

EDIT: Also, it occurred to me that if this dom is correct, then you probably have multiple `media-panel` elements which could cause trouble since each page should have unique `id` elements.  You might need `media-panel` to be a class instead of an id to make things work.

Comment: thanks for your effort, for whatever reason I can seem to get the playlist to be selected. Unfortunately the UI for the site I am trying to modify is rather complex. I'm guessing I'll have to ask some other questions to figure out what I need to do to get it to work

Comment: Maybe you can clarify where you're trying the click stuff?  Like where does `$('#playlist-menu .row').removeClass('selected');` and `$(this).addClass("selected");` happen?  or where did you try `$(this).click()`?  Where you put those calls is going to be important because it will define what `this` is.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things wrong in your code. Most importantly, and the main reason why your code is not working as intended, is because **your selectors are wrong**. You are selecting with

```
$('#playlist-menu .row').each()
//...
("#media-panel .row").each()
```

You are using [`Descendant Selectors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors), which selects any element with a `.row` class under `#playlist-menu` and `#media-panel` respectively. This causes you to select the songs **twice**; once for playlist-menu loop and once again for media-panel loop. You should instead use  [`Child Selectors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) to target the right elements.

```
$('#playlist-menu > .row').each()
//...
(".media-panel .row").each()
```

Also, I do not understand why you add and/or remove `.selected` class while you are iterating through the elements for indexing purposes.

And lastly, when checking to see if something exists with `indexOf`, you should check for `equality to -1`. Your usage is not something that would break your code in this specific situation, but it may do so in some others.

Here is a fiddle. I believe it works as you wanted : http://jsfiddle.net/9frb61c3/2/

**Edit**: Another mistake i had overlooked is, As @mr rogers pointed out, `ID`s should be unique in the DOM. Change your `media-panel` to `class`es.